# Explicit formula for autobiographical numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

Recently I heard about autobiographical numbers. They are kind of self-descriptive numbers, where the $i$-th digit at is the number of occurrences of the digit $i$ in the number. For example, consider $1210$. Its first digit $1$ is the number of $0$s in the number; the next digit $2$ is the number of $1$s in the number, and so on.

[Reference](https://brilliant.org/courses/ace-the-amc/introduction-120/autobiographical-numbers/1/?utm_medium=sponsor&utm_source=youtube&utm_campaign=teded_070818_quiz)

My question is: Is it be possible for any formula to yield the $n$-th autobiographical number (the sequence is starting from $1210$ and goes on)?

Comment: No, there is no formula known. The sequence is [OEIS A046043](https://oeis.org/A046043), namely $$1210,2020,21200,3211000,42101000,521001000,6210001000.$$ These are all autobiographical numbers.

Comment: Why after 10 digits they are not found ?

Comment: By definition, the autobiographies can not have more than 10 digits - see the link.

Comment: I like the name "autobiographic" ; I will attempt once to define "narcissic" numbers...

Comment: You can [interpolate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) the numbers if you want, though the formula will be highly ineffecient.